# How to get carrier privileges for Android app?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, certificate, carrier, uicc

Could you help me with eSIM(eUICC) carrier app for Android. My app needs to activate the eSIM on the device with an activation code, but without system permissions.
I have read the docs and am having problems with the signing process. [Part of docs](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/esim-overview#carrier-privileges).

So where do I go to get the public-key certificate that I need to sign my app to give the app [carrier privileges](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/uicc#rules_on_uicc)?
My customer already sells eSIM, but eSIM activation is done manually, which causes some problems for some users.

And if you can help with Xamarin/MAUI code/tutorials that would be great.

I've been working through the docs and don't understand how or where I can get the app signing certificate. [Implementing eSIM article](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/esim-overview#activate-esim-carrier-app), [UICC Carrier Privileges](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/uicc#rules_on_uicc)

Comment: In my understanding it is the other way round: the sim card contains your app signature and by this this makes your app a carrier app of that SIM card. So the app signature has to be included into the downloadable eSIM. https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/carrier#how_privilege_is_granted_to_a_carrier_app The necessary steps are shown in the link already included in your question: https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/esim-overview#carrier-privileges